# Azure maps close htmlMarker popup programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Can't seem to close the azure maps htmlMarker popup programmatically using popup.close()

I'm using azure maps to display htmlMarkers on the map and using azure maps htmlMarkers to display a popup when a marker is clicked. Azure maps htmlMarker popup provides a close button on the popup but I need the popup to close when a user clicks the Add to Route button on the popup. As per azure maps documentation popup.close should work but I can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to close the popup attached to an HTML marker programmatically.

The first, if you know it is open, is to use the markers `togglePopup` function.

```js
 marker.togglePopup();
```

The second is to get the popup instance from the markers options, then call the close function.

```js
marker.getOptions().popup.close();
```